# Python- How to print parallel lists/arrays, neatly, in two columns...?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I will preface this by stating that I am a beginner and this is in regards to a homework assignment in an Intro to Programming class...

I have two parallel lists of employee names and salaries, sorted by ascending salary in increments of thousands. I don't know how many elements will be in the list each time the program runs...it is determined by how many the user inputs each time.

I am currently using the following code in a module to print my lists(represented by parameters 'S' and 'E' for salary and employee):

```
def printArrays(S, E):

    for i in S:
        idx = (S.index(i))
        print ("name:   " + E[idx] + "     salary:   $ %0.3f" % i)
```

---

the output from the above code looks like this:

```
name: Joe Smith     salary: $ 25.500
name: Samantha Johnson     salary: $ 45.750
name: Dan Pak     salary: $ 75.000
```

---

What I would like are neat columns that are not staggered. Better yet, I would like the output to look like this...

```
Employee name:     Salary:

Joe Smith          $ 25.500
Samantha Johnson   $ 45.750
Dan Pak            $ 75.000
```

I can't use a dictionary because my results must remain sorted by salary value.

Comment: look up the `.format` method in python. You can give column width in that.

Answer (score 3):

```
def printArrays(S, E):
    for i in S:
        idx = (S.index(i))
        print ("name: {0:>10} salary: ${1:>10}".format ( E[idx], i )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a python module called **prettytable** that might be handy in your case, [see here](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial). You would be able to do like that:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def printArrays(S, E):

   tbl = PrettyTable(["Employee name", "Salary"])

   for i in S:
      idx = (S.index(i))
      tbl.add_row([E[idx], i])

   print tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in S:
    idx = (S.index(i))
    print('%-20s $ %0.3f' % (E[idx], i))
```

`'%20s'` instead of `'%-20s'` would align to right.

If you want to fill a dynamic width, [string.ljust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) and [string.rjust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust) are your friends:

```
max_width = max([len(x) for x in E])
for i in S:
    idx = (S.index(i))
    print('%s $ %0.3f' % (E[idx].ljust(max_width), i))
```

Of course it can be done with str.format, too. It's even more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Off-topic, but since you are learning, this could help you:

```
for i in S:
    idx = (S.index(i))
```

is terrible.

Use one of the following:

```
for e, s in zip(E,S):

for idx, i in enumerate(S):

for idx in range(len(S)):
```

(the first is better because it is more fail proof, it will only iterate on the smallest array if they don't have the same size).

Also, naming variables `E` and `S` is not very good. `salaries` and `employees` would be better.

Going further, you could define a simple structure like so:

```
employees = [{'name': name, 'salary': salary} for name, salary in zip(E,S)]
```

Then you can iterate directly on that list and get the values you need:

```
for employee in employees:
    print("name: {name:>10} salary: ${salary:>10}".format(**employee))
```